# Maven Spring Project givinig me org.slf4j.spi.LocationAwareLogger error

Tags: java, eclipse, spring, maven, spring-mvc

Maven Spring Project givinig me

```
org.slf4j.spi.LocationAwareLogger.log(Lorg/slf4j/Marker;Ljava/lang/String;ILjava/lang/String;Ljava/lang/Throwable error
```

This is the first time I am using Eclipse and Maven.. I always did my Spring projects in Eclipse but I just started to use Maven for the JARs.  If I run my new project on a server I get this error:

```
SEVERE: Exception sending context initialized event to listener instance of class org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener
java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.slf4j.spi.LocationAwareLogger.log(Lorg/slf4j/Marker;Ljava/lang/String;ILjava/lang/String;Ljava/lang/Throwable;)V
    at org.apache.commons.logging.impl.SLF4JLocationAwareLog.info(SLF4JLocationAwareLog.java:159)
    at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader.initWebApplicationContext(ContextLoader.java:273)
    at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener.contextInitialized(ContextLoaderListener.java:111)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.listenerStart(StandardContext.java:4206)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.start(StandardContext.java:4705)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.start(ContainerBase.java:1057)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.start(StandardHost.java:840)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.start(ContainerBase.java:1057)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngine.start(StandardEngine.java:463)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardService.start(StandardService.java:525)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardServer.start(StandardServer.java:754)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina.start(Catalina.java:595)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:616)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap.start(Bootstrap.java:289)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap.main(Bootstrap.java:414)
Sep 12, 2012 2:37:13 PM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext start
```

Here is my pom.xml file, something must be missing

```xml
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/maven-v4_0_0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <groupId>org.springsource.greenbeans.maven</groupId>
    <artifactId>WebFlowTemplate</artifactId>
    <packaging>war</packaging>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <name>WebFlowTemplate Maven Webapp</name>
    <url>http://maven.apache.org</url>
    <dependencies>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>jstl</groupId>
            <artifactId>jstl</artifactId>
            <version>1.2</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
            <artifactId>hibernate-core</artifactId>
            <version>3.6.3.Final</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
            <artifactId>hibernate-validator</artifactId>
            <version>4.3.0.Final</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>junit</groupId>
            <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
            <version>3.8.1</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.aspectj</groupId>
            <artifactId>aspectjtools</artifactId>
            <version>1.6.2</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-aspects</artifactId>
            <version>3.1.2.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-context</artifactId>
            <version>3.1.2.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.webflow</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-webflow</artifactId>
            <version>2.3.1.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-security-core</artifactId>
            <version>3.1.2.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-security-web</artifactId>
            <version>3.1.2.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-security-config</artifactId>
            <version>3.1.2.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-security-ldap</artifactId>
            <version>3.1.2.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>



        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-aop</artifactId>
            <version>3.1.2.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>


        <dependency>
            <groupId>log4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>log4j</artifactId>
            <version>1.2.17</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>c3p0</groupId>
            <artifactId>c3p0</artifactId>
            <version>0.9.1.2</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.ldap</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-ldap-core</artifactId>
            <version>1.3.0.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.ldap</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-ldap-core-tiger</artifactId>
            <version>1.3.0.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>


        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.jasig.cas</groupId>
            <artifactId>cas-server-core</artifactId>
            <version>3.5.0</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>slf4j-api</artifactId>
            <version>1.6.6</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>slf4j-ext</artifactId>
            <version>1.6.6</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>slf4j-log4j12</artifactId>
            <version>1.6.6</version>
        </dependency>

    </dependencies>
    <build>
        <finalName>WebFlowTemplate</finalName>
    </build>
</project>
```

please help me

Comment: that reads like version compatibility issues to me. It is looking for the method .log inside org.slf4j.spi.LocationAwareLogger and its not found or isn't the same return expectation.

Answer (score 8):

You can use the mvn-plugin ***maven-enforcer-plugin*** to identify your
problems with ***commons-logging***.

Add this snippet to your *master* or *parent* ***pom.xml***

```xml
<plugins>
  <plugin>
    <artifactId>maven-enforcer-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>1.1.1</version>
    <executions>
      <execution>
        <id>enforce-banned-dependencies</id>
        <goals>
          <goal>enforce</goal>
        </goals>
        <configuration>
          <rules>
            <bannedDependencies>
              <searchTransitive>true</searchTransitive>
              <excludes>
                <exclude>commons-logging</exclude>
                <exclude>org.slf4j:1.5*</exclude>
                <exclude>org.slf4j:1.6*</exclude>
                <exclude>org.springframework:2.*</exclude>
                <exclude>org.springframework:3.0.*</exclude>
              </excludes>
            </bannedDependencies>
          </rules>
          <fail>true</fail>
        </configuration>
      </execution>
    </executions>
  </plugin>
  ......
</plugins>
```

The right mvn-configuration in your project for logging ***slf4j*** within ***log4j*** could be:

```xml
<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
        <artifactId>slf4j-api</artifactId>
        <version>1.7.1</version>
    </dependency>
    <!-- slf4j-bridge for commons-logging -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
        <artifactId>jcl-over-slf4j</artifactId>
        <version>1.7.1</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>  
        <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>  
        <artifactId>slf4j-log4j12</artifactId>  
        <version>1.7.1</version>  
    </dependency>
    ...
</dependencies>
```

This could produces e. g. that error

```
...
[INFO] --- maven-enforcer-plugin:1.1.1:enforce (enforce-banned-dependencies) @ sd4h ---
[WARNING] Rule 0: org.apache.maven.plugins.enforcer.BannedDependencies failed with message:
Found Banned Dependency: commons-logging:commons-logging:jar:1.1.1
Use 'mvn dependency:tree' to locate the source of the banned dependencies.
...
```

It can be solved, when it will be ***excluded*** in your mvn configuration e. g.

```xml
<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-context</artifactId>
        <version>3.1.2.RELEASE</version>
        <exclusions>
            <exclusion>
                <artifactId>commons-logging</artifactId>
                <groupId>commons-logging</groupId>
            </exclusion>
        </exclusions>
    </dependency>
    ...
</dependencies>
```

Answer (score 6):

I had the same problem and i **SOLVED** it updating the **jcl-over-slf4j** jar file. 
I'm using **1.7.5** version and it succesfully deploys.

Here is my pom.xml's dependencies. Hope this help you.

```
     <properties>
    <spring.version>3.2.3.RELEASE</spring.version>
    <spring-security.version>3.1.4.RELEASE</spring-security.version>
    <org.aspectj-version>1.7.2</org.aspectj-version>
    <org.slf4j-version>1.7.5</org.slf4j-version>

</properties>
<dependencies>
    <!-- Spring 3 -->
    <dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-context</artifactId>
    <version>${spring.version}</version>
    <exclusions>
        <exclusion>
            <artifactId>commons-logging</artifactId>
            <groupId>commons-logging</groupId>
        </exclusion>
    </exclusions>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-core</artifactId>
        <version>${spring.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-web</artifactId>
        <version>${spring.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-webmvc</artifactId>
        <version>${spring.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-jdbc</artifactId>
        <version>${spring.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <!-- Spring Security -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-security-core</artifactId>
        <version>${spring-security.version}</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-security-web</artifactId>
        <version>${spring-security.version}</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-security-config</artifactId>
        <version>${spring-security.version}</version>
    </dependency>

    <!-- DataBase Connection -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>mysql</groupId>
        <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
        <version>5.1.25</version>
    </dependency>

    <!-- Tiles 3 -->

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.tiles</groupId>
        <artifactId>tiles-extras</artifactId>
        <version>3.0.1</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
        <artifactId>slf4j-log4j12</artifactId>
        <version>${org.slf4j-version}</version>
    </dependency>

    <!-- slf4j-bridge for commons-logging -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
        <artifactId>jcl-over-slf4j</artifactId>
        <version>${org.slf4j-version}</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
        <artifactId>slf4j-log4j12</artifactId>
        <version>${org.slf4j-version}</version>
    </dependency>

</dependencies>
```

Answer (score 2):

run

`mvn dependency:tree` or `mvn dependency:list` to get a list over all your dependencies including the transitive ones.

Answer (score 1):

This issue has been bugging me for some time and it appears to catch quite a number of people.([See here also](http://forum.springsource.org/showthread.php?124753-Spring-mvc-sample-project-slf4j-problem)) Fresh install of STS, download latest MVC template, builds OK, won't run because of this SLF4J issue.

This issue appears to be incompatibilities between slf4j libraries and dependencies that are used by maven.

The easy solution ([here](http://forum.springsource.org/showthread.php?124753-Spring-mvc-sample-project-slf4j-problem)) is to edit the pom and remove the exclusion for commons-logging, and then delete the dependencies for slf4j. Spring drops back to commons logging when slf4j is not available.
The harder solution I gave up on and that is to track down which versions work with the current shipping STS(3.1) and ensure that the template works with the correct versions.

I hope this post assists others who have tried the template and cannot get it to run out of the box as it should.

Answer (score 0):

There is some version conflict between some commons logging lib and one of the slf4j libs.
*(This is not a maven problem, it is a problem that occures if you maintain the libs by hand too.)*

Open the maven pom with eclipse. There is a Tab called "hirarchy" it will show the used and required versions. Try to use a cobination of the logging liaries that does not have so much conflicts.

---

I have had a look at your pom. The problem is the `jcl-over-slf4j-1.5.8.jar` it CONTAINS some org.apache.commons.loggin jars that are not compatible to slf4j 1.6.6.

`jcl-over-slf4j-1.5.8.jar` is referenced by `org.jasig.cas`

What I would try is to replace the `jcl-over-slf4j-1.5.8.jar` with `jcl-over-slf4j-1.6.6.jar`

```xml
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.jasig.cas</groupId>
        <artifactId>cas-server-core</artifactId>
        <version>3.5.0</version>
        <exclusions>
            <exclusion>
                <artifactId>jcl-over-slf4j</artifactId>
                <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
            </exclusion>
        </exclusions>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
        <artifactId>jcl-over-slf4j</artifactId>
        <version>1.6.6</version>
    </dependency>
```

But I do not know cas-server-core 3.5.0 is compatible with `jcl-over-slf4j-1.6.6.jar`. But in most cases the "outer" API of an logging framework is more stable then the "inner" API that is used by the logging Bridges. -- So good luck.

Comment: Yes, either exclude jcl-over-slf4j from cas-server-core, or, preferably, directly declare a dependency on jcl-over-slf4j 1.6.6

Comment: You don't need the exclusion _and_ the direct dependency. The version of the closer one will win every time.

Comment: once I made the change I got this error: ava.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.springframework.core.env.ConfigurableEnvironment.merge(Lorg/springframework/core/env/ConfigurableEnvironment;

Comment: @Clive Evans: you are right, one do not need both, but I wanted to make it explicite

Comment: @PartyWithJohn: check what slf4j version is required by spring, and then use this instead of 1.6.6